# What is PAGEIOLATCH_SH wait type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I have a query that is taking a long time in the middle of a transaction. When I get the `wait_type` of the process it is `PAGEIOLATCH_SH`.

What does this wait type mean and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

From [**Microsoft documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql):

> `PAGEIOLATCH_SH`
>
> Occurs when a task is waiting on a latch for a buffer that is in an `I/O` request. The latch request is in Shared mode. Long waits may indicate problems with the disk subsystem.

In practice, this almost always happens due to large scans over big tables. It almost never happens in queries that use indexes efficiently.

If your query is like this:

```
Select * from <table> where <col1> = <value> order by <PrimaryKey>
```

, check that you have a composite index on `(col1, col_primary_key)`.

If you don't have one, then you'll need either a full `INDEX SCAN` if the `PRIMARY KEY` is chosen, or a `SORT` if an index on `col1` is chosen.

Both of them are very disk `I/O` consuming operations on large tables.

Comment: It's a real simple query. Select * from <table> where <col1> = <value> order by <PrimaryKey>. We also have an index on just col1 and have tried rebuilding the index.

Comment: Can you suggest some resources for learning the understanding you have of what is disk intensive, what requires a full index scan, what requires a sort etc

Comment: @GregB: if you already have a basic knowledge of SQL, you could read Joe Celko's books (all of them but especially `SQL for Smarties` and `Thinking in Sets`) and my blog of course :)

Comment: This did indicate an error in our disk subsystem. A RAID disk had failed without triggering the monitoring system. Checking the event logs found that SMART had indeed marked a drive as bad.

Answer (score 10):

`PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type usually comes up as the result of fragmented or unoptimized index.

Often reasons for excessive `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type are:

- I/O subsystem has a problem or is misconfigured
- Overloaded I/O subsystem by other processes that are producing the high I/O activity
- Bad index management
- Logical or physical drive misconception
- Network issues/latency
- Memory pressure
- Synchronous Mirroring and AlwaysOn AG

In order to try and resolve having high `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type, you can check:

- SQL Server, queries and indexes, as very often this could be found as a root cause of the excessive `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait types
- For memory pressure before jumping into any I/O subsystem troubleshooting

Always keep in mind that in case of high safety Mirroring or synchronous-commit availability in AlwaysOn AG, increased/excessive `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` can be expected.

You can find more details about this topic in the article [Handling excessive SQL Server PAGEIOLATCH_SH wait types](https://www.sqlshack.com/handling-excessive-sql-server-pageiolatch_sh-wait-types/)