# SQL Server 2008 - Query takes forever to finish even though work is actually done

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

Running the following simple query in SSMS:

UPDATE tblEntityAddress
SET strPostCode= REPLACE(strPostCode,' ','')

The update to the data (at least in memory) is complete in under a minute.  I verified this by performing another query with transaction isolation level read uncommitted.  The update query, however, continues to run for another 30 minutes.  What is the issue here?  Is this caused by a delay to write to disk?

TIA

Comment: Looking at the logs, I'm seeing errors like:

SQL Server has encountered 2336 occurrences of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds...

A lot of these are to tempdb.  Could this be caused by autogrowth being set to 1 MB?

Comment: possibly.  1mb is a pretty low icrement (and most dba's will yell at you for autogrowth anyway).  on the database, right click and go to reports, and click the Disk Usage Report.  on this report there is a section for autogrowth/shrink events.  use this to see if you're getting a lot of these events.

Comment: This was corrected (and I agree on autogrowth.  A higher up disagrees, unfortunately).  The problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you transaction is locked by another transaction which affected `tblEntityAddress`.

Run `sp_lock` and see if `tblEntityAddress` is locked by another process.

Comment: See my comment on the question, above

Comment: @Brian: seems you have a problem with the disk subsystem indeed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620626/what-is-pageiolatch-sh-wait-type-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

In a separate SSMS window, try running the following:

```
SELECT status, wait_type
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = <SPID>
```

Just replaced  with the SPID associated with your UPDATE query (number in brackets after  your login name in the bottom bar).

Run the above a few times in succession and note what the wait_type is. There are numerous types of waits - see what that is (& let use know), it could highlight the cause.

**Update:**
Quotes from [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822101):

IO_COMPLETION

> This waittype indicates that the SPID
>   is waiting for the I/O requests to
>   complete. When you notice this
>   waittype for an SPID in the
>   sysprocesses system table, you must
>   identify the disk bottlenecks by using
>   the performance monitor counters,
>   profiler trace, the
>   fn_virtualfilestats system
>   table-valued function, and the
>   SHOWPLAN option to analyze the query
>   plans that correspond to the SPID. You
>   can reduce this waittype by adding
>   additional I/O bandwidth or balancing
>   I/O across other drives. You can also
>   reduce I/O by using indexing, look for
>   bad query plans, and look for memory
>   pressure.

Comment: Already did this.  Receiving the following two waits:

IO_Completion
PAGEIOLATCH_EX

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is a slow running trigger.