# What would be reason behid WaitType PAGEIOLATCH_SH?

Tags: performance, t-sql, ssis, performancecounter

I am executing a stord proc that basically truncates & reload the table x.During reload of data , It joins table a , table b that contains 100 millions & 2 millions records resp.During the execution of stored proc i found in activity monitor that WaitType PAGEIOLATCH_SH  is slowing down my sp.
what would be the reason behind this waittype "PAGEIOLATCH_SH". And how to avoid this waittype.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what are you RAID values and file placements?

Comment: I am using activity monitor.I couldnt see RAID value in that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PAGEIOLATCH\_SH wait type in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620626/what-is-pageiolatch-sh-wait-type-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful
[What is PAGEIOLATCH_SH wait type in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620626/what-is-pageiolatch-sh-wait-type-in-sql-server)