# What does the wait type PREEMPTIVE_XE_DISPATCHER mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I am receiving `PREEMPTIVE_XE_DISPATCHER` wait type in SQL Server wait analysis.

I am not sure the reason being this wait type is on the top can somebody please let me know why its on the top list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is associated with Extended Events background threads, go check which ones you have active, you can ignore it if it is "System Health".

Anyways, more info: 
[MSDN Link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd6aafb2-b9b4-4e31-966f-0529150e2319/wait-statistics-preemptivexedispatcher?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

[MSDN link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql)

[Stack Overflow related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620626/what-is-pageiolatch-sh-wait-type-in-sql-server)

Comment: i already refer this blog, but can this wait type is related to PAGEIOLATCH_* ?

Comment: you are refering to the PAGEIOLATCH_EX wait type correct?

Comment: PAGEIOLATCH_* occures during long waits, so it happens i.e during a long database scan, and yes I think they are related.

Comment: You should investigate this, since it can turn out making your server very slow to react to simple queries.

Comment: Refer to all the links in my answer